# How can a variable be displayed within speech marks in lua?

Tags: string, variables, lua, coronasdk

This is the code (corona SDK btw), it is calling a physicsdata (unimportant).

```
 r = math.random(1,5)
local scaleFactor = 1.0
local physicsData = (require "retro").physicsData(scaleFactor)
physics.addBody( enemy, physicsData:get(r) )
```

The r in

```
 physicsData:get(r) )
```

has to be inside speech marks to work (I tested).

how can the r variable be string-ilised? ( :D  )

Comment: What are "speach marks"?

Comment: Sorry Nicol.

Sorry to Ihf too.

Comment: @andrew: I wasn't talking about your spelling; I don't know what you mean by "speech marks". Do you mean "quotation marks?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a string,

```
tostring(r)
```

For example,

```
physics.addBody( enemy, physicsData:get(tostring(r)) )
```

If you really need quotes in the string (I doubt you do):

```
physics.addBody( enemy, physicsData:get('"' .. tostring(r) .. '"') )
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to [concatenate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenation) the strings. In Lua the concatenate operator is .. so you need to write something like:

```
"The value of the variable is "..var
```